# Check if SKCameraNode view contains a node of a certain class?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

The SKCameraNode has two methods to it for checking node visibility inside it's viewport. (.containsNode() and .containedNodeSet())
The first return a bool, which is what I'm looking for. Checking for one node object works fine.

```
if myCamera.containsNode(mySpriteNode) == false {}
```

But I want to check wether it contains nodes of a class.

```
if myCamera.containsNode(MyClass()) == false {}
```

Since it doesn't work I wonder how this would be done.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the other method you mentioned `containedNodeSet().`  This will return `Set<SKNode>` which you can then inspect as you wish, for example:

```
for node in cameraNode.containedNodeSet() {

    if  let interestingNode =  node as? InterestingClass {
        // Do something useful here 
    }
}
```